# CORS blocked even when using CORS allow extension on browser

Tags: vue.js, axios, cors

I'm trying to recover some data from a government api from my country.
But i'm having a issue with CORS.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/bolsa-familia-por-municipio?mesAno=202004&codigoIbge=5300108&pagina=1' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

That's the error and this line of code is my axios code:

```
 let headers = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'chave-api-dados': 'cec73fb24c54ff134d2053da6b471467'
    }
    axios
        .get(url, { headers })
        .then((response) => {
            const { benefits } = response.data;
            this.gov_benefitsF = benefits;
            console.log(benefits);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            this.errored = true
        })
        .finally(() => this.loading = false)
```

What should I do to make this working? I'm using this extension [CORS Allow Access](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlfand) and there's nothing working here

Comment: It is up to the remote resource to provide the correct CORS headers.

Comment: they provided my a 'Accept':'*/*'.

Answer (score 1):

Browser extensions which add CORS headers in responses don’t generate responses to pre-flight OPTIONS requests.

You need the server to grant you permission, or to use a proxy.

Comment: So I need to create proxy inside my axios? I don't know about that.

Comment: No. You need to make a request *to* a proxy. The proxy needs to be server-side.

Comment: Any direction of how I search a tutorial for this? never done.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible since it's not a public API scheme the server must have specified the addresses for API request and with that you need a way to get add to the server beside you are on a local address